# Attaching a file into PDF with Latex

Tags: embedding

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\textattachfile[mimetype=audio/wav,created=D:2012042200000000'00',modified=D:2012042200000000'00']{./kop-echo.wav}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{./geluidspictogram.png}}

\end{document}
```

Embedding a (sound) file using the `attach` package works, but the only reason for me not implementing it is that the resulting PDF file shows an ugly empty comments square (I don't need) when I hover over the embedded icon. Can this be suppressed, or is this just the way Acrobat Reader works?

[image: Screen dump]